# How to compose forkIO and SqlPersistM

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm struggling with the best approach to compose `forkIO` with DB action (`SqlPersistM`). Note: `SqlPersistM` is defined [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#t:SqlPersistM), and is basically a `ReaderT SqlBackend (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO))`. Here's a simplified version of the problematic code:

```
startBot :: SqlPersistM ()
startBot = do
  chan <- liftIO newChan
  forkIO $ forever (processIncomingMessages chan) -- How to do do this?
  forkIO $ forever (processOutgoingMessages chan) -- And this?
  return ()

processIncomingMessages :: Chan -> SqlPersistM ()

processOutgoingMessages :: Chan -> SqlPersistM ()

main = runSqlite ":memory:" startBot
```

Is it even possible to fork **inside** the `SqlPersistM` action being passed to `runSqlite`? Or should one be putting the `runSqlite` action inside the fork? Will the former result in "race conditions" sort? Will bot the threads be able to synchronize their use of the underlying DB connection?

**More context:** `processIncomingMessages` receives input from a network API, parses them, and pushes them on to `chan`. `processOutgoingMessages` reads from `chan`, runs some transformations and send data out to a different network API. Both the functions interact with the data while processing the incoming/outgoing messages.

Comment: Can someone please explain why I got the downvote? Are these kind of questions not encouraged here?

Comment: Are you aware of [`resourceForkIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:resourceForkIO). From the docs - "If you are allocating a resource that should be shared by multiple threads, and will be held for a long time, you should allocate it at the beginning of a new ResourceT block and then call resourceForkIO from there." I believe it fits your use case - `forever` is a long time, and you are worried about concurrent access.

Comment: To maybe more directly address your question - things will probably break eventually if you use "raw" concurrency in your program. But it seems like the designers of `persistent` have forseen this problem and included a `ResourceT` monad in the monad stack so users have an accepted way to deal with it.

Comment: @user2407038 "you should allocate it at the beginning of a new ResourceT block and then call resourceForkIO from there" what does this mean? Speficially, what is "the beginning of a new ResourceT block"? In my example, is it `forever (processIncomingMessages chan)`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for running `SqlPersistM` you need `runSqlite`. As for getting race conditions, i think it depends on sqlite itself. Check whether it allows concurrent access.

Because `forkIO` and other async stuff work only in `IO` there is no way to drag `SqlPersistM` inside. Well, since it's basically a `ReaderT`, you probably can, but i bet it's not how it is intended to be used. So, IMO, you need to fork threads first and then use `runSqlite` to run persistent actions inside.

Comment: because `startBot` is doing DB access.

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. Can you please elaborate with a code snippet? I'm unable to understand.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about `forkFinally`. You probably need to use some primitive like `Chan` or `MVar`.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Updated again. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you keep in mind that all persistent operations are designed to work inside a transaction (SqlPersistM) than monad stack usage will make more sense.